# Add PPA with Xubuntu packages to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, ppa, xfce

If I'm using the normal Ubuntu (not Xubuntu) 12.04 can I add without getting trouble a Xubuntu ppa like https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10 ?

Comment: I did exactly that on 2012-05-13, and nothing broke. Of course, anything's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you shouldn't have any problems using that PPA and installing packages from it.

Please note that the PPA contains XFCE 4.10, which isn't supported on Ubuntu 12.04, so you will essentially be beta-testing software with the bugs, etc. which accompany it. Put simply: the PPA will work, but the packages may not! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you happen to have something available amongst that ppa's packages installed I doubt it would give you issues.

Why you would want to use that PPA is perhaps another question. Even if you then installed Xubuntu - XFCE4.10 is not officially supported.

Comment: Some folks like to be on the bleeding edge ;)

Comment: I've been running xfce 4.10 for a while (in 12.04 and 12.10) - I just don't have it in ubuntu ;)